# Excel formulas are not working - not recognizing numbers

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula, number-formatting

I've pasted some numbers on Excel spreadsheet and wanted to do some calculations with it. The problem is that Excel isn't recognizing the numbers. I've already tried several methods to convert them into numbers and none of them works: paste/special multiplying by 1; formating each cell to the number/scientific number format. And there isn't also an error message on the top right corner of each cell like I've read on the internet indicating that there is a number written as text. If I retype each number, Excel recognizes it.

To make sure that the problem was really that the numbers were understood by Excel as text, I tried the functions ISNUMBER(), that returned FALSE and ISTEXT() that returned true.

I want to know how I can fix that problem without having to type into each cell.

Ps. the numbers are in scientific number format, i.e., 1,085859E+001

Comment: Have you tried pasting as values? This should paste the content of the cells rather than any associated number/text formatting - worth a try?

Comment: Could you post some examples of your numbers? Also where are you pasting them from?

Comment: Are the values stored as numbers in the location you're getting them from? It sounds like it's already stored as text before being copied to the clipboard. Are you getting them from another application?

Comment: This might also help: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?42119-Solved-Convert-exponential-format-to-a-number

Comment: I'm getting the numbers from a .txt file, which was written by another program. I just checked and they are indeed stored as text, but is there a way that I can make Excel identify them as numbers?

Answer (score 4):

Since the column is text the cells are formatted as text.
you use Value to convert the text into a number so the formula will work

A2 = 123
A3 = 123 Richard
Formula
=isnumber(A2) result is false 
use
=isnumber(value(A2)) result is True

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, until I realized that the decimal separator was set as (,) instead of (.) in the default settings. Once I changed that, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your "numbers" are being detected as text, you can use `VALUE()` to make sure Excel understands that it is actually a number.

```
A1: `1.23E+10 (this is a  string)
B1: =VALUE(A1)
    =12300000000
C1: 1.23E+10 (this is a number)
D1: =IF(B1==C1,"It worked", "Uh Oh")
    =It Worked (for me anyway)
```

I'm not sure what the comma in your scientific number will do so might want to have the function replace them if there not required.

Comment: The comma is the separator, it works just as the dot (it is the standard in my country and my Excel is already formated to accept it). When I type =VALUE(A1), I get an error #VALUE!

Comment: Separator for what? Thousands or decimal place? I found that if I replace the "." in 1.23 with a "," I get a #VALUE too. If I go into options and set the thousands separator to "." and decimal one to "," instead of using "system default" it does work.

Answer (score 0):

See Kenneth Hobs' answer here: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?42119-Solved-Convert-exponential-format-to-a-number

Open your Excel File, Press Alt + f11 to open the VBA screen, 
Go to Insert > Module, Copy and Paste Kenneth's code:

```
Sub Expo()
    Dim cell As Range, s() As String, lng As Long, n As Integer
    For Each cell In Selection
    With cell
        If Not VarType(.Value2) = vbString Then GoTo NextCell
        s() = Split(cell.Value2, "E")
        .Value2 = s(0) * 1 * (1 * 10 ^ s(1)) 'ePart(s(1))
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
NextCell:
    Next cell
End Sub
```

You can now run it as a macro to convert selected cells. Or if you want it as a function copy this code instead:

```
Function Expo(cell As Range)
    Dim s() As String

    With cell
        If VarType(.Value2) = vbString Then
            s() = Split(.Value2, "E")
            Expo = s(0) * 1 * (1 * 10 ^ s(1)) 'ePart(s(1))
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

This way you can use it as a normal function in excel eg =Expo(A1)

As I mentioned in the comments above though, you will have already lost some degree of accuracy when the original number was converted to scientific notation. The best solution is to get the originating program to write the proper numbers into the text file if you can.

Comment: I skipped on the scientific notation and simply multiplied by 1 - worked for me anyways.  Thanks for the code snippet!

Answer (score 0):

Open a new word document and try Pasting the web content in word first, the copy this content from the word document and paste special in excel, as text. This simple solution worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Open a new blank Excel, then go to **`Data > From Text`**, this way you can import text and designate which format you want to convert to.  On the `Text Import Wizard` page, select either `Delimited` or `Fixed width` (I am not sure how your original text file look like but generally it should be `Delimited`.  On the next page, pick a `Delimiter` or enter one in Others.  On step 3, you should see the data listed below and the data format on the upper left.  Pick **`General`** for those columns that you believe should not be Text.  This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

My case was stubborn, no response to Paste Special or CLEAN(). Finally resolved by copying the offending column of Excel data and pasting into new Notepad++ doc. This revealed a leading "?" in all the bad numbers (apparently some non-printing character). Used Search > Replace to find all "?" and replace with nothing. Edit > Select All, copy to a new Excel column, and voilà!

Answer (score 0):

There may be hidden characters. Trailing/leading spaces may not visible and hence erroneously be neglected. If there is trailing/leading Space characters with numeric values, excel consider it as text.

Copy contents problematic cells to MS-Word [(Select problematic cells and copy them to MS-Word)] and check any hidden characters, Remove hidden characters with "find"/"replace" functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with numbers from PPT (e.g. ($3,000))pasted to excel.  Tried multiple different ways to get the text to recognize including find replacing parens, commas, $ signs to blank and trying to format so excel could run formulas.  The only option that worked was to paste to Word first then paste value to excel which worked without any additional formatting steps.  Surprised I could not do it all within excel though.  Maybe there's another way

Answer (score 0):

- Select all the cells to convert to a number.
- |Data| Menu Tab > Data Tools > [Text to columns]

  - Delimited. [Next]
  - Deselect all "Delimiters". [Next]
  - "Column data format" > General
  - [Finish]

Verify by using `=ISNUMBER(C16)` in an spare cell, where `C16` is a sample cell. Should now return `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me lately. I had forgotten that I had set formula **re**calculation to manual. The weird thing is that it was returing FALSE when initially created (which was correct) but given the test depended on the value of other cells that, when changed, did not trigger the change in the cell with the isnumber() formula.

Pressing F9 "fixed" my problem (and my ignorance).